# How do I make my image perfectly centered with the text?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I tried using display flex but they're not perfectly aligned, this image is somehow a bit wider than the text and I don't know how to fix this, this is how it looks on the page
[image]

```css
#gym {
    width: 10%;
    height: 80%;
}

.side-bar {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background-color: rgb(230, 224, 224);
    width: 20%;
    height: 80%;
}

.side-bar ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 10%;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

.side-bar ul li {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.side-bar ul a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-bar">
<ul>
    <li><img src="gym.png" alt="gym logo" id="gym"><a href="#">Gym</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Today</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">This Week</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tomorrow</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Next Year</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add into .side-bar ul li  `display: flex; align-items: center;`

Comment: That aligned the whole list in the middle, not the list item

Comment: Yes, my bad. Try the .side-bar ul li. Make its display flex too if needed

Comment: That works, it does align the items perfectly, but it creates a space between the items that gets fixed by modifying margin.

Comment: Since the whole li element is flex too now you can modify the "justify-content: center;" attribute too. Or in whichever direction you want it to be, like flex-start, flex-end, space-round etc.

Answer (score 0):

[image: This is how it will look]

```
.side-bar ul li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
}

.side-bar ul li a {
  align-self: center;
}

.side-bar ul li img {
  align-self: center;
}
```